# canvas imageData manipulation

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am playing with canvases imageData and I am having some issues with speed. What I am doing is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        loadCanvas();
        myImageData();

});
function loadCanvas(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    image = new Image();
    image.src = '/static/images/teeth1.jpg';
    image.onload = function (){
        imageWidth = image.width;
        imageHeight = image.height;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        imageData = myImageData(context, image);
        pixels = imageData.data;
        console.log(pixels);
        console.log(pixels.length);
        console.log(imageData);  

        //Changing the value of each pixel
        for (var y=0; y<=imageHeight; ++y){
            for (var x=0; x<=imageWidth; ++x){
                index = (y*imageWidth + x) * 4;
                pixels[index] += 30;
                pixels[++index] += 30;
                pixels[++index] += 30;
            }
        }                       
    }   

}
function myImageData(context){
    console.log("width: "+image.width+", height:"+image.height)
    return context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
}
```

When I execute the above code outside the onload function from chrome's console it works very fast. But when executing the double for's inside the onload function (as it is right now) it hangs. Why is that? Is it because it is inside the onload? How can I make sure the image was fully loaded before executing the double fors(so to put them seperatelly outside the onload function)?

Comment: how big is you image ?

Comment: 460x288. but it works good from chrome's console

Comment: There is some discrepancy in how your myImageData is defined and how you call it.

Comment: how come?And where is that discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Define functions before using them (Good to)
function loadCanvas(){     
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); // Define variables!
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var image = new Image();     
    image.onload = function (){
        var imageWidth  = image.width;  // Variables again!
        var imageHeight = image.height;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight );
        var imageData = myImageData(context, image); // Variables!
        var pixels = imageData.data;
        console.log(pixels);
        console.log(pixels.length);
        console.log(imageData);  
        //Changing the value of each pixel
        for (var y=0; y<=imageHeight; ++y){
            for (var x=0; x<=imageWidth; ++x){
                var index = (y*imageWidth + x) * 4;
                pixels[index] += 30;
                pixels[++index] += 30;
                pixels[++index] += 30;
            }
        }                      
    };
    image.src = '/static/images/teeth1.jpg'; // Set src here
}
function myImageData(ctx, img){  // Pass the actual image as argument
    console.log("width: "+img.width+", height:"+img.height);
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadCanvas();    // has myImageData() so...
    //myImageData(); // why??
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I had that for testing puposes to see if myImageData gets called before the onload callback returns and forgot to remove it. Works great now. Thank you :)